# void reduce(); MEMBER FUNCTION REDUCES FRACTIONS

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

This is the member function I need to write. The function is meant to reduce a fraction. 
void reduce();

this is what I have

```
void reduce()

{
    num /= gcd();
    den /= gcd();
}
```

The gcd function was provided, so it is not incorrect.

It is not allowing me to incude my code for the rest of the class definition because its too long

My question is;
why am I getting an error for the reduce()

i also tried

```
void reduce()
// reduce this fraction to simplest form. For instance,
// 2/4 will be reduced to 1/2
{
    int a = gcd();
    den /= a;
    num /= a;
}
```

and my code is testing it with:

```
// Test reduce

f1.reduce(); // f1 is -4/5
f2.reduce(); // f2 is 2/3
if(f1.get_numerator() != -4 || f1.get_denominator() != 5 || f2. 
get_numerator() != 2 || f2.get_denominator() != 3)
{
    cout <<"The reduce function was wrong.\n";
    result -= 0.5;
}
```

Comment: [How do I ask a question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What error? What's not working. What has this to do with operator-overloading. We don't even know the types of num/def or the return type of gcd.... How are we supposed to help if we don't know all this?

Comment: What error? Imagine it's not your own problem. Imagine you are coming to a question that somebody else wrote. Can you even understand what is being asked from this post alone? Please visit the [help] and read up on [ask] good questions. In particular focus on the part that explains how to create [mcve]s.

Comment: Without you providing enough information, do you think people over the internet have psychic power to magically know why you are getting an error?

Comment: Useful when debugging (and always): don't just print that the result was wrong, also print what that result was and what it should have been. And test one thing at a time so you can tell which thing is wrong. "At least one of these two things went wrong" is not nearly as helpful as "this should have been -4/5, but it is 29/73".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the value returned by `gcd()` depends on `num` and `den`, the value returned by `gcd()` in the first line will be different than the value returned by `gcd()` in the second line.

Store the return value of `gcd()` in a local variable and use it.

```
void reduce()
{
    auto g = gcd();
    num /= g;
    den /= g;
}
```

---

Add some debugging output to your program:

```
if ( f1.get_numerator() != -4 ||
     f1.get_denominator() != 5 ||
     f2.get_numerator() != 2 ||
     f2.get_denominator() != 3)
{
   cout <<"The reduce function was wrong.\n";

   if ( f1.get_numerator() != -4 )
   {
      cout << "Expected value of f1.get_numerator(): " << -4 << "\n";
      cout << "Actual value of f1.get_numerator(): " << f1.get_numerator() << "\n";
   }
   else
   {
      cout << "Got the expected value of f1.get_numerator()\n";
   }

   if ( f1.get_denominator() != 5 )
   {
      cout << "Expected value of f1.get_denominator(): " << 5 << "\n";
      cout << "Actual value of f1.get_denominator(): " << f1.get_denominator() << "\n";
   }
   else
   {
      cout << "Got the expected value of f1.get_denominator()\n";
   }


   if ( f2.get_numerator() != 2 )
   {
      cout << "Expected value of f2.get_numerator(): " << 2 << "\n";
      cout << "Actual value of f2.get_numerator(): " << f2.get_numerator() << "\n";
   else
   {
      cout << "Got the expected value of f2.get_numerator()\n";
   }

   if ( f2.get_denominator() != 3 )
   {
      cout << "Expected value of f2.get_denominator(): " << 3 << "\n";
      cout << "Actual value of f2.get_denominator(): " << f2.get_denominator() << "\n";
   }
   else
   {
      cout << "Got the expected value of f2.get_denominator()\n";
   }

    result -= 0.5;
}
```

Comment: great, that is what I ended up doing, but still not working D:
I tied to add the rest of the code, but it says there is too much code and not enough detail

Comment: @KatPantle can you at least update your question with the codes that you tried and it's not working?

Comment: @KatPantle, You can (1) Try to create a [mcve] and post it, (2) Learn [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: hang in there with me for a moment. Thank you for the advice. Is what I added useful?

Comment: @KatPantle, see the updated answer. That is one way you can troubleshoot problems in your code.